# How to connect Android (JAVA) with SQL Server with (collation Urdu_100_CI_AI)

Tags: java, android, sql-server, database-connection, jtds

I am using SQL server 2008 r2, Android Studio, jtds/jtds-1.2.7.jar.zip( 293 k) driver
My Database Collation is Urdu_100_CI_AI
When I try to make a connection this exception occurs:

java.sql.SQLException: The USE database statement failed because the database collation Urdu_100_CI_AI is not recognized by older client drivers. Try upgrading the client operating system or applying a service update to the database client software, or use a different collation. See SQL Server Books Online for more information on changing collations.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: The error is obvious ... jtds driver doesn't work with Urdu_100_CI_AI Collation

Comment: i don't know! what is  "Urdu_100_CI_AI Collation"?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect android directly to SQL database, moreover you can use SQLlite which is an inbuild function of android .

Comment: *You cannot connect android directly to SQL database* **yes, you can**, but it is not a good solution ...

Comment: plese describe the best way to access my sql server database